# MongoDB - Golang Library

Tags: mongodb, go

Is there an official golang library for MongoDB?  I am using the latest version of Mongo just released - 3.4.

Best I can find is:

https://labix.org/mgo

However this hasnt had a release since late 2015?

Thanks!

Comment: Any other issues with mgo but release date?

Answer (score 2):

mgo is the driver developed by Community (maintained by Gustavo Niemeyer, an engineer at Canonical), mgo is quoted in the official documentation of mongodb:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/#community-supported-drivers

Last update was August/2016 (this year):
https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an official golang library for MongoDB

Yes, there is: [GoDoc: mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) or see [Github: mongodb/mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).

The new MongoDB official driver was released on 19th Feb 2018. Currently still in alpha version. 
For more information see also [Blog: Considering The Community Effects of Introducing An Official Golang MongoDB Driver](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/considering-the-community-effects-of-introducing-an-official-golang-mongodb-driver)

Answer (score 0):

**Latest answer to your question is 'Yes'.**

MongoDB official driver for Golang is released its v1.0.0 in 13th March 2019

You can see the steps to use it on [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) as well as in [godoc](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo)